# How to subtract two numeric strings

Tags: php

I have two strings of numeric type, but the result is coming wrong.

```
$totalamount='41,305.33';
$normalamount='999.72';
echo $total=$totalamount-$normalamount;
```

Is there any other way to do it or issue with my own code.

Comment: You might want to lose the `echo` or the `$total=` (depending on whether you want to output the difference or just calculate it).  Having both *ought* to work, as assignment is an expression (which basically evaluates to the value assigned), but doing both in one statement is a little creepy.

Comment: It will work as expected above if you simply remove the comma. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You got a wrong value due to ',' character, simply remove them...

```
$totalamount='41,305.33';
$normalamount='999.72';
echo (double)str_replace(',','',$totalamount)-
     (double)str_replace(',','',$normalamount);
```

Comment: Not in mine. Those numeric vars still being formatted strings so next time you want operate with them you must convert them again. Also, in the case those vars were formatted according to a given locale, the decimal point may be different.

Comment: And if you are not going to store the conversion within a variable, manual casting to `double` lacks of sense.

Answer (score 2):

the cause of the error is that the string has comma on it.

```
$totalamount = floatval(str_replace(',', '','41,305.33'));
$normalamount = floatval(str_replace(',', '','999.72'));
echo $total = $totalamount-$normalamount;
```

btw, **[doubleval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.doubleval.php)** — Alias of **[`floatval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)**

Comment: Note, casting to a number is not strictly necessary -- PHP will do it for you as part of the math.  It only matters if you're trying to subtract objects or something, and at that point your math is going to be screwy anyway.

Comment: @cHao I agree with you. I was just trying to show how casting also works :) maybe for future reference.

Comment: There is no need to call `floatval` here.

Comment: @Ultimater If you got a numeric var, it is better to keep it in a number format. Otherwise, PHP will need to cast it to a number on each operation. Yes, "there is no need", but it is a good practice.

Comment: @jackflash: It's good practice if you're reusing the values a lot.  If you're using them once, then it's noise.

Comment: @cHao The cast is gonna be done anyway so if you cast manually then you got a better code, ready for possible future changes. You can call it "noise", but I think "good practice" fits better.

Comment: @jackflash:  I call it another arbitrary thing someone has to know in order to read your code.  Hence, "noise".  Screw "possible future changes"; hypothetical future scenarios are not worth coding for if it adds noise.  If you don't need it now, it shouldn't be there.  If you need it later, then *add* it later -- at that point, the benefits outweigh the cost.

Comment: @cHao It's clear that we have different opinions :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a reverse function for `number_format()`.

**Solution:**

```
function number_unformat($number, $dec_point = '.', $thousands_sep = ',') {
    return (float)str_replace(array($thousands_sep, $dec_point),
                              array('', '.'),
                              $number);
}

$totalamount  = number_unformat('41,305.33');
$normalamount = number_unformat('999.72');
$total        = $totalamount - $normalamount;
echo $total;
```

**Output:**

```
40305.61
```

Comment: PHP already has this functionality http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

Comment: There is no need to define such a complex function to handle such a simple operation.

Comment: @Ultimater And what if `$totalamount` is retrieved from a DB or from the user? It's not as easy as "remove the comma and PHP will handle it".

Comment: Yes it is:
`$totalamount=str_replace(',', '',$totalamount);`
`$normalamount=str_replace(',', '',$normalamount);`

Comment: @Ultimater Imagine that `$totalamount` has been formatted with `number_format()` according to a given locale. That would not work if thousands separator is another than `,`. Also, it is much better to keep a numeric var in a number type so PHP won't have to cast it on each future operation.

Comment: Neither will your code unless you provide a specific 3rd parameter. So whatever we send to your function we simply replace the `,` in my code to suit your needs.

Comment: @Ultimater The default param values in my function are the same as in [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `floatval()` to achieve what you're looking for, but you need to remove the "," from the strings:

```
$totalamount = str_replace(',' , '', '41,305.33');
$normalamount = '999.72';
echo $totalamount - $normalamount;

// Writes: 40305.61
```

Comment: Very redundant. `str_replace(',' , '', '41,305.33') - '999.72'` would do it.

Comment: There is no need to float twice.

Comment: @BenM There is no need to manual cast but in fact it is a very good practice, so your code was better before.

Comment: @jackflash: He was casting twice with `(float)` and `floatval()`.

Comment: @AlixAxel Just saw the revisions. Sorry. But cast once is better than nothing, anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the comma and it works as expected.
There is no need to convert the string to a number manually because the minus operator does this for us.

```
<?php
$totalamount='41305.33';
$normalamount='999.72';
echo $total=$totalamount-$normalamount;
```

The reason `'41,305.33'-'999.72'` results in `-958.72` is because PHP, as soon as it sees a comma, considers it an invalid digit and trims the remaining characters off. Thus you are left with `'41'-'999.72'` which is indeed `-958.72`.

Comment: This is absolutely correct, and it's the only answer that explains why this happens. Why the downvotes?! +1 to count-act.

Comment: @Alix: I want to guess that it's been downvoted because the correct answer to "i have this data that's giving me problems..." isn't "use different data".  If it weren't for the explanations, this would actually be a non-answer.  The data might be coming from a DB or something. (I mean, who actually types out `'41,305.33'` in real code, when `41305.33` is better all around?  This is obviously a minimal example.)  The answer would have been a lot better with some code to convert the "invalid" data into something that works (as the `str_replace` examples did).

Answer (score -1):

You could convert your formatted numbers to numbers PHP understands using the [NumberFormatter](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php)

```
$fmt = numfmt_create('de_DE', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
echo $total = $fmt->parse('41,305.33') - $fmt->parse('999.72');
```