# How to subtract minutes in PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to know how to subtract two variables that represent minutes in PHP

For example I have two minute variables

```
$minutes1 = 20;
$minutes2 = 45;

$totalMinutes = $minutes1 -$minutes2;
//output should be 35 as $totalMinutes
```

An example would be

```
$time1 = "2:20";
$time2 = "3:45";

$finalTime = $time2 - $time1
//final time = 1:25
```

I am only interested in the minutes and not the hours

Comment: How does 20 minutes - 45 minutes = 35 minutes?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson 35 minutes into the previous hour. Like 2:20 - 45 minutes = 1:35

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969413/how-to-subtract-two-numeric-strings

Comment: You really need to be _clear_ in your question. We can't guess what you mean, nor do we want to assume.

Comment: From the top of my head, use the decimal equivalent of your minutes and only convert when displaying.

Comment: 20 minus 45 does not equal 35. I'm wondering how you came about to make that mathematical equation.

Comment: @developer_117 I am only interested In the minute aspect
I will update my question

Comment: Just subtract and if less than zero, add 60 until greater than zero, else if greater than 60, mod 60.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that there's some cleaner way, but this seem to do what you're asking for.

```
$m1   = 20;
$m2   = 45;

$diff = $m1 - $m2;    
echo $diff >= 0 ? $diff : $diff + 60;
```

This returns `35`. Demo: https://3v4l.org/WaC8r

Comment: So what about `"1:15"` and `"3:05"`, is the difference `70` minutes?

Comment: @localheinz - Considering that the OP only mentioned minutes (when I wrote this answer), I only go by the minutes. In the original question, the OP didn't mention any hours at all.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Based on comments I have a better understanding of what you are asking for and have written this function.

```
function subtractMinutes($start, $sub) {
     $res = $start;
     while ($sub > 0) {
         if ($sub >= 60) {
             $sub -= 60;
             continue;
         }
         if ($res >= $sub) {
             $res -= $sub;
             break;
         }
         if ($sub > $res) {
             $sub -= $res + 1;
             $res = 59;
             continue;
         }
         $sub -= $res;
         $res = 0;
     }
     return $res;
 }

var_dump(subtractMinutes(20, 45)); //35
var_dump(subtractMinutes(20, 60)); //20
var_dump(subtractMinutes(20, 120)); //20
var_dump(subtractMinutes(20, 121)); //19
var_dump(subtractMinutes(40, 40)); //0
var_dump(subtractMinutes(59, 58)); //1
```

Comment: Please read the comments on the question before posting an answer.

Comment: 45 minus 20 does not equal 35, it's 25 as you did state. However, the  OP's question is way too unclear. OP's commented code: `//output should be 35 as $totalMinutes`

Comment: @Fred-ii- The question is poorly written. He means eg 10:20 - 45 minutes which equals 09:35

Comment: @GregKos I couldn't agree more.

Comment: I posted before the comments were posted, I'm updating the answer now. @Fred-ii- I thought 35 was a typo, therefore "I think you mean 25".

Comment: @JimWright It's real hard to say for certain. I hope you haven't fallen into a rabbit hole here.

Answer (score 0):

> Please note that this answer attempts to provide a general solution.
>   If you only need to subtract a couple of times by all means, just
>   check with 60.

I would insist on suggesting you should be using decimals for all operations, and only turn into the correct format when outputting the result on a page. I believe it is safer to do calculations this way, instead of relying on you remembering to add/subtract 60 every time.

Examples:

```
$single_minute = 1.66;
$twenty_minutes = 20*1.66 = 33.2;
$sixty_minutes = 60*1.66 = 99.6;
```

When outputing:

```
$out_twenty = round(33.2/1.66);
$out_sixty = round(99.6/1.66);
```

You can use helper constants:

```
define("MINUTE", 1.66);
//You want to calculate 34 minutes
$thirtyfour_minutes = MINUTE * 34;
//You want to output 34 minutes
echo round($thirtyfour_minutes);
```